# Как установить год меньше 1900г в DatePicker?

Tags: java, android

Делаю так:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("year", 1856);
    args.putInt("month", 2);
    args.putInt("day", 12);
DialogFragment dateDialog = new DatePicker(); 
    dateDialog.setArguments(args);
    dateDialog.setTargetFragment(dateDialog, GET_DATE);
    dateDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
    dateDialog.getClass().getName());
```

выставляет 01.01.1900.
Как указать, что можно вводить года и раньше 1900 года?

Answer (score 4):

У [`DatePicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) по умолчанию минимальной датой стоит `01.01.1900`

Чтобы это исправить попробуйте метод [`datePicker.setMinDate(long minDate);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long))

Нулем считается `0:00:00 1 января 1970`'го года. Так что вам надо будет отрицательное число передавать, если хотите год меньше `1970`.

Для максимальной даты так же стоит ограничение `31.12.2100`. C ней всё аналогично — метод [`setMaxDate(long maxDate)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate(long))

Comment: Как это сделать в моем случае, ведь я создаю экземпляр класса DatePicker()? Как сделать установки в нем?

Comment: вызываете dateDialog.setMinDate() перед методом show()

Comment: у dateDialog нет метода setMinDate()

Comment: dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate() ну нажмите точку. посмотрите какие методы вам студия подсказывает, почитайте документацию про этот метод. как и где его вызывать

Comment: Я это сразу сделал, но ничего похожего на setMinDate не нашел. Поэтому и задал здесь вопрос.